# Simple Javascript on html textbox conversion. Doesn't work twice

Tags: javascript, html, replace, onclick, getelementbyid

I'm using the replace method and if I type in "test test" only the first test gets converted to good so it'll become "good test". I'm at a loss on why this is happening. On a side question, if I was to add 20 other words that I would like to replace, would I have to create 20 different str.replace?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to replace "Test" with "Good"</p>

<textarea id="firstbox"></textarea>
<textarea id="secondbox"></textarea>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Change</button>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var str = document.getElementById("firstbox").value.toLowerCase()
        var res = str.replace("test", "good");
        document.getElementById("secondbox").value = res;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Use regex, change `"good"` to `/good/g`

```js
function myFunction() {
        var str = document.getElementById("firstbox").value.toLowerCase()
        var res = str.replace(/test/g, "good");
        document.getElementById("secondbox").value = res;
    }
```

```html
<p>Click the button to replace "Test" with "Good"</p>

<textarea id="firstbox"></textarea>
<textarea id="secondbox"></textarea>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Change</button>
```

Comment: Hello, do you know how I could put multiple replace strings, sort of like a dictionary translation.

Comment: could you give an example? Do you mean you want to replace multiple words with one word, or do you have a map of words and translations you want to replace (Example var map={'test':'good','test2':bad,etc})?